# paypal ipn missing letters on transaction array

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

would anyone tell me if this is an IPN correct response? I found no documentation indicating the index transactions with missing letters. Has anyone experienced this problem?

```
{
    "payment_request_date": "Wed Nov 20 18:27:12 PST 2013",
    "return_url": "https://www.xxxx.com/payment/confirmation?tid=6cabb650-5254-11e3-b556-417057e4769f",
    "fees_payer": "EACHRECEIVER",
    "ipn_notification_url": "https://www.xxxx.com/payment/paypal/ipn?tid=6cabb650-5254-11e3-b556-417057e4769f",
    "sender_email": "sender@xxxx.com",
    "verify_sign": "Axib8Qr9snmjWbcBJ4CIf7btl81aAI8SG1XiXJt3ayuBCZlhX9OfmLc6",
    "test_ipn": "1",
    "transaction": {
        "0].id_for_sender_tx": "730140804D999991E",
        "0].receive": "bob-facilitator@gmail.com",
        "0].is_primary_receive": "false",
        "0].i": "2YM92644S8890074S",
        "0].statu": "Completed",
        "0].paymentTyp": "SERVICE",
        "0].status_for_sender_tx": "Completed",
        "0].pending_reaso": "NONE",
        "0].amoun": "USD 15.00",
        "__proto__": {}
    },
    "cancel_url": "https://www.xxxx.com/payment/canceled?tid=6cabb650-5254-11e3-b556-417057e4769f",
    "pay_key": "AP-2KN00752WL371LLSA",
    "action_type": "PAY",
    "transaction_type": "Adaptive Payment PAY",
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction": "false",
    "charset": "windows-1252",
    "notify_version": "UNVERSIONED",
    "reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error": "false",
    "__proto__": {}
}
```

Trasaction malformed:

```
"transaction": {
    "0].id_for_sender_tx": "730140804D999991E",
    "0].receive": "bob-facilitator@gmail.com",
    "0].is_primary_receive": "false",
    "0].i": "2YM92644S8890074S",
    "0].statu": "Completed",
    "0].paymentTyp": "SERVICE",
    "0].status_for_sender_tx": "Completed",
    "0].pending_reaso": "NONE",
    "0].amoun": "USD 15.00",
    "__proto__": {}
},
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the raw data and it is right. The problem is that sails-express bodyParser is parsing in a wrong way. I've changed the bodyParser to:

```
module.exports = {
    express: {
        'bodyParser' : function(options){
            var _urlencoded = urlencoded(options)
            , _multipart = multipart(options)
            , _json = json(options);

            return function bodyParser(req, res, next) {

                var buf = '';
                req.setEncoding('utf8');
                req.on('data', function(chunk){ buf += chunk });
                req.on('end', function(){
                    req.rawBody = buf;
                });             

                _json(req, res, function(err){
                    if (err) return next(err);
                        _urlencoded(req, res, function(err){
                            if (err) return next(err);
                                _multipart(req, res, next);
                        });
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

and the ipn validation functions using the new req.rawBody attribute.

Thanks all,